# 3D cursor always placed despite not being selected tool

Tags: 3d-cursor

At some point in the inbetween versions i started placing the 3D cursor regardless of having it selected as a tool.

I was wondering if there's an option to disable that as i am myself yet unable to find it?

it causes unwanted behavior having to drag the mouse a little bit to activate the tools instead of one click bringing up the submenu. (other tips on how to lodge the submenu in place are welcome)

thanks in advance!

[image: Having this tool as not selected]

Not having this selected.

Comment: 3d cursor is not a tool, you have not to select anything to place it in the scene. I mean that red-white circle, Maybe some screenshots will help to get what you mean exactly. As for the submenus, there is a checkbox in the user preferences Interface / Menus / Open on mouse over.

Comment: Awesome, and if the 3D cursor isnt in the tool shelf then do you know what the white cross plus red-white circle tool happens to be in the toolshelf? (2.80 btw)

Comment: Oh, that's new fancy 2.8. Btw, I've never ran it, and you've never said that you use this particular version. That's the only version that has the cursor as a tool, so that results in some confusion.